# CoreData iCloud changes not saved

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I m making an app with CoreData and iCloud integration. I went through the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3) to adapt my already working app to integrate iCloud synchronization.

Inserting objects and deleting seems to be working fine. When I delete the app and reinstall it on my phone all synchronized data are correctly restored.

My issue is when I modify an NSManagedObject. The context which I used to query CoreData to fetch my object does not detect any changes on my objects when I modify a field. Therefore the context is not saved. If I try to force saving context even when no changes are detected, nothing is saved.

I went through stack oververflow and found that the context must have a stalenessInterval set to 0.0. This did nothing to my app. Do you have any idea on what could be wrong ?

I noticed that the context carried by the NSManagedObject seems different than the one I used to fetch data. If I call save method on this context, nothing happened either.

I am completely lost, since I thought it would ba as easy as inserting and deleting objects.

Thanks for your help !

(ps: I code with Swift but even Objective C code is acceptable as answer :) )

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to use two databases whereas I should have used configurations to separate entities saved to the cloud and those saved locally.

For those who wants more information on CoreData with iCloud i suggest to go through this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/227/) from Apple WWDC 2012 which helps a lot getting into this subject.